# List all block devices size with Java

Tags: java, linux

I would like to list all block devices connected on Linux machine. Is there a way to list the name of the devices, size and partitions with Java?

Comment: In general for low level OS specific information you need to find a command line program which will do this and call it. If no such command line program exists, you might need to write one in C to obtain this information.